# C# VS2013 and VS2015 Assemblies

Tags: c#

i would like to load assemblies during runtime and this is possible as I know, but somebody know, if i can load Assemblies compiled in C# 5.0 (VS2013) in a C# 6.0 (VS2015) main application?

Comment: C# version doesn't matter.  .NET version of both applications matters.

Answer (score 4):

What matters is the CLR version and any referenced assemblies. As by default both VS2013 and VS2015 target the .NET 4.0 CLR with the .NET 4.5 BCLs - and thanks to things like binding-redirects there is no problem.

Note that .NET is designed to be backward compatible - you can load a 2.0 CLR assembly (even a 1.1 in some cases) in a 4.0 environment, but the .NET 2.0 CLR is dead unless you're targeting Windows Mobile / Windows CE.